# Angular 13 - Attach headers to form, to bypass annoying Microsoft AAD SSO Issue

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

Good Day

I'm working on a Microsoft AAD SSO integration, and I'm stuck on the logout stage. To process the login I use an anchor tag: `<a [href]="loginLink">SSO Login</a>` to prevent a CORS issue.  This works and I get back my ID / JWT, which I can register with my backend (C# / Entity).  When I go to logout, the backend wants me to access an API which is protected with a bearer token, but I'm unclear how to attach the header data.

```
<form [action]="logoutLink"
      style="position: absolute; top: 9999rem;"
      method="POST"
      aria-hidden="true"
      #SSOLogout></form>

logout() {
    this.SSOLogout.nativeelement.submit();
}
```

`logout()` is being called from a "sign-out" button, which is when I trigger the form.submit(), to bypass the CORS issue.  The backend is directly passing the data through to a SAML2 Library, and if I use a standard HTTP or Fetch call, I run into CORS problems.

Is there a way to add header data to that form element?  I know I could attach the data in the body, but the backend doesn't think it's a good idea, to spite the fact I think it's the only possible way to give them the bearer token, and prevent CORS issues.

We can't find any setting or configuration on the Microsoft AAD to adjust the CORS Settings, and we can't tweak our WebServers (I already tried).

Sorry if this is a stupid / annoying question, but I want to make sure I'm either right or wrong.

Comment: I do not think you can add a header. You’re basically delegating the form submit to the browser..?

Comment: What about using an interceptor to add headers for this specific request!

Comment: I can vote it up, but we didn't end up going with that solution, I'll assume it might work.

Comment: The answer we went with was to separate the calls.  I still fire the call to the backend with a standard Angular HTTP call, but we call the SSO Logout with an href on an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

•   You can add CORS configuration in an Angular app by adding the below **CORS policy** code in ***‘startup.cs’*** which will be able to call the ***‘TodoListAPI’***. You can set it to allow any domain and methods.

```
   ‘ services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
      {
         builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
})); ‘
```

•   Once, the above has been done, then you can configure headers by providing a service that wraps the original **‘HTTPClient’** object from Angular instead of **‘HTTP’* like below: -

```
‘ import { HttpClient } from './http-client';

  export class MyComponent {
   // Notice we inject "our" HttpClient here, naming it Http so it's easier
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
   this.http = httpClient;
 }

  handleSomething() {
     this.http.post(url, data).subscribe(result => {
    // console.log( result );
      });
     }
     } ’
```

•   For more information on using multi providers for the **‘Http’** class by providing your own class and extending the **‘Http’** one, please refer the link below: -

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html

You can also refer the below link for more details on configuring the authentication mechanism for an Angular app from end to end: -

https://www.ifourtechnolab.com/blog/angular-login-with-session-authentication

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we ended up breaking up the call and using an anchor tag <a> to fire the SSO Logout up to the AAD.  The other call to the backend is handle as per normal.